# EDITED: How should I separate closely related programs in C#? (user client, admin, and common class library)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a suite of programs that are related. One is a user client, one is an admin program, and another is a set of library classes that reside in a Class library.

How should I separate the projects?

Should I put the user client in one project, the admin program in another, and the common library in a third project? Or should they reside in separate solutions?

**EDIT:**
George Stocker has, in a good intention i'm sure, edited my question, probably to make it clearer.

however, he has unintentionally reversed the question so all the "yes" answers are now unclear.

sorry about the inconvenient, but i would be glad if everyone who answered here will write, what exactly they thinks that should be in the same solution, and what in a separate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's probably how I'd do it.  It has the advantage of being nice and simple

Edit:
If you're using Visual Studio I'd have one Solution, with 3 projects (client, admin and common).

If you're using something else, then the theory is the same, 3 seperate projects

Comment: how? each in a separate solution?

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio.net they should all be separate projects within the same solution. Due to the lack of information given in the question, I can't say where the splits in the projects should go.

Answer (score 0):

typically I would have a project for each thing (admin,client & common) and a solution for each of the webs (with the common project in both solutions)